# Repeatedly hovering over image causes "mouseenter" to record every hover and fades in and out continuously

Tags: jquery, mouseenter

I have this simple code set up so that when I `mouseenter` an image, the image fades out and some text info fades in. My problem is that when I hover over the image very quickly back and forth, it records every `mouseenter` and fades in and out continuously for the amount of times my mouse hovered over the image. Is there some way to stop this behavior?

```
$('article').mouseenter(function(e) {
    $(this).children('img').fadeTo(500, 0.4);
    $(this).children('.post-info').fadeIn(500);
}).mouseleave(function(e) {
    $(this).children('img').fadeTo(500, 1);
    $(this).children('.post-info').fadeOut(500);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) is the solution

In simple terms, you just add `.stop()` in front of every fade animation.

<kbd>[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/fmnm8qtz/)</kbd>

```
$('article').mouseenter(function(e) {
    $(this).children('img').stop().fadeTo(500, 0.4);
    $(this).children('.post-info').stop().fadeIn(500);
}).mouseleave(function(e) {
    $(this).children('img').stop().fadeTo(500, 1);
    $(this).children('.post-info').stop().fadeOut(500);
});
```

As a bonus. This is how I would've written that code:

<kbd>[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/fmnm8qtz/1/)</kbd>

```
$('article').on("mouseenter mouseleave", function( e ) {

        // mouseenter variable returns true if mouseenter event is occurring 
        // and it returns false if event is anything but mouseenter.
    var mouseenter = e.type === "mouseenter",
        $this = $(this),
        img = $this.children('img'),
        postInfo = $this.children('.post-info');

        // Both of these use ternary if statements that are equal to:
        // if ( mouseenter ) { var imgFade = 0.4; } else { var imgFade = 1; }
        // if ( mouseenter ) { var postInfoFade = 'fadeIn'; } else { var postInfoFade = 'fadeOut'; }
    var imgFade = mouseenter ? 0.4 : 1,
        postInfoFade = mouseenter ? 'fadeIn' : 'fadeOut';

    img.stop().fadeTo( 500, imgFade );
    postInfo.stop()[ postInfoFade ]( 500 );

});
```

Comment: Thank you! Also, I will use your version of the code instead.